# RXJS: Iterate array with click event

Tags: rxjs

I have an observable with array.
I need to make some operation on each element in the array on mouse click event.
I started with something like this:

```
merge([
 this.clicks,
 this.array$
 ]).pipe(
   tap((value) => console.log(value))
 ).subscribe();
```

But how can i iterate the elements, so in each click it will print the next element in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following?

```js
arrayObservable = of(["how", "are", "you"]);

fromEvent(window, "click").pipe(
  switchMapTo(arrayObservable$),
  map((array, index) => {
    return array[index % array.length]
  })
)
```

Hope it helps!